# Cannot find "/usr/bin/gcc" in c_cpp_properties.json (using WSL Debian on Windows) with VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, path

I am writing a program which requires me to include files such as `stdio.h`. However, when I actually write the line `#include <stdio.h>`, there is the error `cannot open source file "stdlib.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers. C/C++(1696)`.

However, I can compile the program without any issue using `gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c -o a`, and the program works perfectly.

The error also appears when I write `#ifndef __STACK_H` (in a .h file), so the error is just annoying.

After installing `gcc` in the following way:

I opened the cmd of Windows in admin mode

```
wsl --install -d Debian
wsl
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I am able to find the `gcc` file with `which gcc` (in `/usr/bin/gcc`).

The error states that I should edit the "CompilerPath" setting. However, the `compilerPath` is already "/usr/bin/gcc".

So I tried multiple `c_cpp_properties.json` files:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc" //error: Cannot find "/usr/bin/gcc".
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "WSL",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc", // error: Cannot find "/usr/bin/gcc".
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And I even tried with the absolute path (which is `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12`), but the error is still here.

How can I fix it?

(Also, this is my first request on Stack Overflow, so I'm not really used to it, sorry for the bad presentation.)

Comment: did you restart VS Code after installing GCC? processes do not automatically pick up changes to system `PATH`. actually, restarting might not help depending on how exactly cpptools is implemented, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I did, I also restared my computer but it did not solve the issue